# Table output of values Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate a table/list in Shiny of the values sampled from a probability distribution ( a list of the sampled values in a table format). I'm new to coding so this is like a foreign language to me. There is probably a lot of errors in the code although I can get it to run just not show the table.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarPanel(
selectInput("dis","Please Select Probability Distribution Type:",
            choices = c("Normal")),
sliderInput("sampleSize","Please Select Sample Size:",
            min = 0,max = 5000,value = 1000,step = 100),
sliderInput("bins","Please Select Number of Bins:",
            min = 1,max = 50,value = 10),
numericInput("sampleMean","Please Enter Sample Mean:",
             min = 0,max = 5000,value = 2500,step = 10),
numericInput("sampleSd","Please Enter Standard Deviation:",
             min = 0,max = 5000,value = 2,step = 10)
   ),


fluidRow(
column(12,
dataTableOutput("table"))
),

mainPanel(
plotOutput("histogram")
)
)

server <- function(input, output){
output$histogram <- renderPlot({
distType <- input$dis
n <- input$sampleSize
bins <- seq(min(input$bins), max(input$bins), length.out = input$bins + 1)

if(distType=="Normal"){
  randomVec <- rnorm(n,mean = as.numeric(input$sampleMean),sd=as.numeric(input$sampleSd))
}

hist(randomVec,breaks=input$bins,col="red")
})

output$table <- renderDataTable({
distType <- input$dis
n <- input$sampleSize
if(distType=="Normal"){

  randomVec <- rnorm(n,mean = as.numeric(input$sampleMean),sd=   as.numeric(input$sampleSd))
  }
  sample(randomVec,100,replace = TRUE)
  })
     }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

From `?renderDataTable` :

> Arguments
>
> expr   An expression that returns a **data frame or a matrix**.

So you can do this:

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
    distType <- input$dis
    n <- input$sampleSize
    if(distType=="Normal"){
      randomVec <- rnorm(n,mean = as.numeric(input$sampleMean),sd=   as.numeric(input$sampleSd))
    }
    data.frame(sample(randomVec,100,replace = TRUE))
  })
```

Comment: Hi @HubertL is there a better way? Also is there a way to show all the values on the same page (multiple columns perhaps). Also thanks for the reply

Comment: As far as I know you can't put data from the same column next to each other freely. The only ways I can think of to do this is by splitting your data into several dataframes and create seperate renderdatatable outputs for each part, all with their own input and output ID's but I can't see this to be user friendly.